# How to invoke a Path Range Index Query using the MarkLogic Java API?

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm looking for an example on how to do a Path Range Index Query using the MarkLogic Java API.

/doc1.xml

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>1234</c>
      <d>
        <c>abcd</c>
      </d>
  </b>
</a>
```

/doc2.xml

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>abcd</c>
      <d>
        <c>abcd</c>
      </d>
  </b>
</a>
```

A path range index was created having this path expression with no path namespace:

```
/a/b/c
```

Is this the proper way to invoke a path range index query using the MarkLogic Java API?

```
QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();

StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder(OPTIONS_NAME);

StructuredQueryDefinition querydef = qb.PathIndex("/a/b/c", "abcd")

SearchHandle results = queryMgr.search(querydef, new SearchHandle());
```

Answer (score 3):

You're very close.  Just change your second to last line to this:

```
StructuredQueryDefinition querydef =
    qb.range(qb.pathIndex("/a/b/c"), "string", Operator.EQ, "abcd");
```

You don't yet need any options from anything you've described, so you could remove OPTIONS_NAME until you have a reason to specify search options.  Also, make sure your path range index has the default collation or else specify the correct collation to your range method call.